# XBAP unable to start in IE10

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xbap, windows-server-2012

I created a simple XBAP WPF application but when I try to browse it, I get this error:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18010
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18010 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/timothy/Downloads/temp%20(2).xbap

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : temp.xbap, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d411194368b9a73a, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * An exception occurred while downloading the manifest. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///C:/Users/timothy/Downloads/temp.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\timothy\Downloads\temp.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\timothy\Downloads\temp.exe.manifest'.
        + Could not find file 'C:\Users\timothy\Downloads\temp.exe.manifest'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    No phase information is available.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [4/3/2013 12:49:01 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading file:///C:/Users/timothy/Downloads/temp.exe.manifest did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindCore(Boolean blocking, TempFile& tempDeploy, TempDirectory& tempAppDir, FileStream& refTransaction, String& productName)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindAsyncWorker()
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\timothy\Downloads\temp.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\timothy\Downloads\temp.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        - Could not find file 'C:\Users\timothy\Downloads\temp.exe.manifest'.
        - Source: mscorlib
        - Stack trace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
            at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

I am debugging it locally but get this error. I am running on Win server 2012. Could anybody please help me solve this issue?

Comment: developed on a different machine? path C:\Users\timothy is correct?

Answer (score 0):

please check that temp.exe.manifest file in the location "C:\Users\timothy\Downloads\"